# How should i store user and user_sessions as HKEY in Redis?

Tags: postgresql, session, redis, hash, hashset

I have Users table which holds passwords, role, profile id and etc. Also i have table User_sessions which holds user_id, session_id, expiry date, user_role and few other data.

Question is i want to store all data in Redis without allocating to much memory. Considering having 2 million users with 5 million non expired sessions is there ways to store data in 4-8GB RAM Redis.

In first scenario i will store user table in Postgres while storing session data in Redis. Session keys will be random UID or any other string 16-64byte

Question 1: Is it good solution to store session as HKEY with default Redis configuration? I suspect that Hashkey has its limit for repeating the Key. Any strategy you recommend ?

Question 2: Should i store User table in Redis as well ?

Question 3: Is it good to query data in Redis or Postgres (no joins) for data count less than 1000 considering that it will be with every call? i.e Permission table which will be called in every request to check permission of Role for that call.

Right now i use Postgres to query for permission wonder is it worth to switch to Redis.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

General answer: It's easy to overthink a solution. Start with a simple, robust solution and adjust only when you see there is a clear case for improvements.

Answer 1: It could be a good solution depending on your user pattern. Regarding the uniqness of the key, you could probably just use `session_id`. Depending on how you generate the `session_id`, you could use `user_id:session_id` to make it more unique.

Answer 2: If you decide to store `user_session` in Redis and you also need `user` at the same time, you should probably store both tables in Redis. Otherwise no.

Answer 3: If you only have 1000 records there's probably no need for a cache at all, unless you want the lowest latency possible. It's all dependent on your user pattern.

Comment: in general i agree with overthinking. But regarding saving user_id:session_id can be somehow tricky sometimes since in my case i dont expose user_id to user. So i have to stick with session_id or generate new non predictible user_id like UUID

Comment: Yes, it all depends. But the main reason to use Redis is to get the performance benefits (besides to reduce load on main DB). You should try to design the query pattern with that in mind. That is, design the data model for read patterns. Use the data types and keys that gives you the lowest number of queries.